VB6 Migration - icons display with black outline on Windows Server 2019
I'm working on migrating a VB6 application that uses ImageList and Image controls to display icons. The application works correctly on Windows Server 2008 R2, but when I run it on Windows Server 2019, the icons have a black outline, which wasn’t the case previously.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue while migrating VB6 apps?
Private Sub Form_Load()
    ' Initialize ImageList control
    ImageList1.ListImages.Add , , LoadPicture("icon.ico")

    ' Assign an icon from ImageList to an Image control
    Image1.Picture = ImageList1.ListImages(1).Picture
End Sub

I suspect this could be related to a rendering issue or compatibility problem between VB6 and newer Windows versions.

Generally speaking I have not seen this kind of problem.  Can you add an image of your icon?  Does it use anything unusual like transparency, high color bit depth, etc.?

Here's a recent and similar question that may be of some use.
